# fetching data from json in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi i want to achieve a javascript/jquery slider in which  all the data is coming from json file,i want to print all the images and some of image discription of the images and i want to slide all the data with corresponding to the images like bootstrap 3 below is the json file ,Can you please tell me how to achieve this

```
{
    data: [{
        slug: "allsopp-allsopp",
        id: 401,
        imageToken: "d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27",
        name: "Allsopp & Allsopp",
        location: "Dubai",
        description: "Allsopp & Allsopp is a family",
        residentialForRentCount: 521,
        residentialForSaleCount: 1114,
        commercialForRentCount: 1,
        commercialForSaleCount: 0,
        commercialTotalCount: 1,
        totalProperties: 1636,
        agentCount: 57,
        licenseLabel: "RERA",
        licenseNumber: "1815",
        phone: "+971 4 429 4444",
        links: {
            self: "/en/broker/allsopp-allsopp-401",
            logo: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27/desktop",
            logo2x: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/d045e18526f988cceb63b08e71180fb6595d9f27/desktop2x"
        }
    },
    {
        slug: "espace-real-estate",
        id: 524,
        imageToken: "2d4dfd5c40d4079dd962adf2fd6277dc3e1e9f2e",
        name: "Espace Real Estate",
        location: "Dubai",
        description: "UAE. Tel no: 043069999 ORN:936",
        residentialForRentCount: 366,
        residentialForSaleCount: 355,
        commercialForRentCount: 0,
        commercialForSaleCount: 1,
        commercialTotalCount: 1,
        totalProperties: 722,
        agentCount: 34,
        licenseLabel: "RERA",
        licenseNumber: "936",
        phone: "04 306 9999",
        links: {
            self: "/en/broker/espace-real-estate-524",
            logo: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/2d4dfd5c40d4079dd962adf2fd6277dc3e1e9f2e/desktop",
            logo2x: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/images/pf_broker/logo/2d4dfd5c40d4079dd962adf2fd6277dc3e1e9f2e/desktop2x"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: use double quotes here to make it json links: "{    }"

Answer (score 0):

Described on the jQuery API site: [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
would suggest something like:

html:

```
<div id='slider'>

</div>
```

js:

```
$.getJSON( 'pathToJsonFile', function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function() {
    var $thisImage = this.links.logo2x,
         $thisDesc = this.description;
    items.push( "<li ><img src='" + $thisImage + "'/> " + $thisDesc + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "#slider" );
 });
```

to cycle through the data elements and append them as list items to the slider list before calling your chosen image slider on that div.

Comment: logo2x contains the image link,i want to slide the description with the image

Comment: edited, your container json array doesn't appear to have a name? but hopefully this structure/approach works as a basis

Comment: I am not able to understand,can you please help how to fetch json data from external file

Comment: should be easier, explanation and example on the jquery api site: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: $getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

Comment: revised answer for ext json file path and based on jquery getJSON api documentation